# How to prove that $g$ is continuous?

Tags: continuity, solution-verification

I have to prove that $g$ is continous but my TA has told me my argumentation is not correct. Can you guys please explain where it goes wrong? I know the following:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continous and let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$g(t) = f(ta+(1-t)b)$$

I have done the following. Let $(t_k)_{k=1}^\infty \rightarrow r$ for $k \rightarrow \infty$. As $f$ is continous we have
\begin{align}\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(t^k) &= f(\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} t^k)\\
&= f(\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (t^k+(1-t^k)b)) = f(r)\end{align}
but he has told me that this does not make any sense? I have used the above to say that 
\begin{align}\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g(t^k) &= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(t^ka+(1-t^k)b)\\
&= f(\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (t^ka+(1-t^k)b))\\
&= f(ra+(1-t)b)\end{align}
and we are done as $g(t^k) \rightarrow g(r)$ and therefore is continous. Is this not correct? And if so what should I be doing different.

Comment: There are many typos in your answer. $t^k$ should read $t_k$ (your TA perhaps thought that you meant the $k$-th power of $t$) and in the last displayed equation, $f(ra+(1-\color{red}{t})b)$ should read $f(ra+(1-\color{red}{r})b)$

Comment: Oh sure. I see. I have done that in my assignemnt as well. I just misstyped in here. But does it make sense to let $(t^k)^\infty_{k=1} \in \mathbb{R}$ as $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer doesn't make sense, as explained in an answer below. But I don't see any mistake in the second paragraph. While the domain of $f$  is $\mathbb R^n$, the domain of $g$ is $\mathbb R$. So, to prove the continuity of $g$ at a point $t$, it suffices to prove that $\{g(t_k)\}$ converges to $g(t)$ for every sequence $\{t_k\}$ that converges to $t$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(lim((t_k)$ is not equal to $f(lim(t_ka+(1-t_k)b)$  you have to write $lim(g(t_k))=limf(t_ka+(1-t_k)b)=f(lim(t_ka+(1-t_k)b)=f(ra+(1-r)b)=g(r)$.

Comment: But do we still use the fact that f is continous? Or is it only the fact that g is continous?

Comment: $limf(t_ka+(1-t_k(=)b)=f(lim(t_ka+(1-t_k)b)$ uses the fact that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes I see. So if $(t^k)_{k=1}^\infty \in \mathbb{R}$ and I do the above calculations we have shown that g is continous? But how do we know the limt exists for g?